# Group By using date, name and amount in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, group-by, nosql

I'm new in using Cassandra and I can't use the Group By, is there a way that I can use the GROUP BY in Cassandra like in SQL? I want to group my data by date and also by the name of the user, and I want to sum all the amount in a specific date. I still don't have a code for this because I don't know how to start and I also aware that the group by is not supported by cassandra

Comment: which Cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Cassandra 3.0.9 I'm having a hard time in filtering the timestamp in Cassandra

Comment: What do you need ? If you want to calculate total amount in a day. you should insert only day,month,year into date field. Ex. For 2016-11-18 you can insert 20161118 as date

Comment: but I'm using the timestamp data type in the Cassandra, and first I need to group the the user name and then group it by date and sum all the amount with the specific date and specific person

Comment: If you are using timestamp then create timestamp only with day, month and year. If you need to group the username first then change the primary key order to PRIMARY KEY (name, date, amount)

Comment: how can I insert the day, month and year only in Cassandra? I'm just an newbie in this database

Comment: Approach 1 : Instead of one timestamp column create three column day, month, year    

Approach 2 : Create date using below method 
   `
   public static Date getDate(int year, int month, int date) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, date);
        return c.getTime();
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use group by without materialized view
But if you want to find the sum of amount for a specific date and name you can get easily.

**Using Apache Cassandra 3.x**

1.Create a table

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    date bigint,
    name text,
    amount double,
    PRIMARY KEY (date, name, amount)
);
```

2.Insert dummy Some data

```
INSERT INTO data (date , name , amount) VALUES ( 1, 'a1', 10);
INSERT INTO data (date , name , amount) VALUES ( 1, 'a1', 20);
INSERT INTO data (date , name , amount) VALUES ( 1, 'a1', 30);
INSERT INTO data (date , name , amount) VALUES ( 1, 'a1', 40);
INSERT INTO data (date , name , amount) VALUES ( 1, 'a2', 50);
INSERT INTO data (date , name , amount) VALUES ( 1, 'a2', 60);
```

3.Now you can find the sum of amount in a specific date and name

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM data WHERE date = 1 AND name = 'a1' ;
```

Comment: Nice solution, that's a very helpful example!